# How can I insert the data as object in array of nested object while I don't know it's depth level

Tags: javascript, arrays, angular, nested-object

I am working on a project of angular where I am making a folder structure.I am inserting data as array of nested object.I am using an array which store the folder name whose we clicked and a another array which store index of folder.
example -

`[{folder1:[{folder2:[{folder3:[]},{folder4:[]}]}]}];`
if I want to make folder in folder 3 then -

> `array =[folder1,folder2,folder3]; index = [0,0,0]`

I don't know it's depth thats'why I use loop-

```
 for(i=0;i<array.length;i++) {
       folder = folder[0][arr[i];
     }
```

now folder variable are overwriting then how can I resolve this problem.

Comment: You might need to use a recursive function here?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You can define a recursive function like this.

It takes in a directory structure array like your array, the targetFolder name and name of folder you want to add in the target folder. It recursively searches for the target folder, if found it adds the folder into the target folder

```js
function addFolder(directory, targetFolder, folderName) {
    if (directory && directory.length) {
        directory.forEach(dir => {
            if (dir[targetFolder]) {
                dir[targetFolder].push({
                    [folderName]: []
                });
            } else {
                const innerDirs = Object.values(dir);
                innerDirs.forEach(d => addFolder(d, targetFolder, folderName))
            }
        });
    }
}

const directory = [{folder1:[{folder2:[{folder3:[]},{folder4:[]}]}]}];

// Adds folder5 into folder3
addFolder(directory, 'folder3', 'folder5'); // [{folder1:[{folder2:[{folder3:[{folder5: []}]},{folder4:[]}]}]}]
```